# RabbitMQ : One queue per message type, or post routing?

Tags: rabbitmq

I use RabbitMQ as an integration distribution system, kind of ETL, pollers are querying tables from source databases, publish results on RabbitMQ, and results are consumed according their source (1 queue per source (app.) to be saved in another form.

I'm asking if it would be better to split queues per query AND source (app..), actually it's done only by source, and "postrouted" using a custom payload header.

The only advantage I see, that could be a defect, is that there are a same number of consumer as there are queries to do. But it could become a problem ...

Thanks.

Comment: Probably, you have do decide it by yourself. It's really hard to suggest anything without knowing project in details. Both ways will serve you good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that one queue per query could get out of hand quickly in terms of managing and monitoring them.

I find it works well to have one queue per *destination*, and to then use the *routing key* to specify how things should be handled within your *consumer* code (i.e. for the *type*). That way, you get *RabbitMQ* to do the multiplexing for you, and the consumer code can run separately on the same messages on each destination point.

There are course, always many different ways, but I find that this tends to work well for *ETL* applications. If you have tons of *destinations*, perhaps you would want to move towards adding the *destination* to the *routing key* as well. If you don't have any ordering requirements (i.e. due to *RDBMS Foreign Key Constraints*), you could also consider adding multiple consumers to the same queue to improve throughput. (For cases where you do have such ordering requirements, that's where the one queue per destination and the multiplexing that provides proves to be especially useful.)

Comment: I have used implicitly your solution, because SQL Query Result, becomes MongoDB Collection. So one to one association.